# Mysql High Concurrency Updates

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I have a mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `coupons` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(255),
    `user_id` INT,
    UNIQUE KEY `code_idx` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The table consists of thousands/millions of codes and initially `user_id` is NULL for everyone.
Now I have a web application which assigns a unique code to thousands of users visiting the application concurrently. I am not sure what is the correct way to handle this considering very high traffic.
The query I have written is:

```
UPDATE coupons SET user_id = <some_id> where user_id is NULL limit 1;
```

And the application runs this query with say a concurrency of 1000 req/sec.

What I have observed is the entire table gets locked and this is not scaling well.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sidhant, I saw the question here for some time already, did you manage to find a solution yet? Could you share it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Nathalie, As a solution what I figured was Mysql was not going to scale for this use case. The solution is to hold the primary key of these coupons in Redis and use a set there.

Answer (score 0):

As it is understood, `coupons` is prepopulated and a `null` `user_id` is updated to one that is not null.

`explain update coupons set user_id = 1 where user_id is null limit 1;`

This is likely requiring an architectural solution, but you may wish to review the explain after ensuring that the table has indexes for the columns treated, and that the facilitate rapid updates.

Adding an index to coupons.user_id, for example alters MySQL's strategy.

```
create unique index user_id_idx on coupons(user_id);
 explain update coupons set user_id = 1 where user_id is null limit 1;
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | coupons | NULL       | range | user_id_idx   | user_id_idx | 5       | const |    6 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So you should work with a DBA to ensure that the database entity is optimized.  Trade-offs need to be considered.

Also, since you have a client application, you have the opportunity to pre-fetch null coupons.user_id and do an update directly on coupons.id.  Curious to hear of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be more suitable for DBA's (and I'm not a DBA) but I'll try to give you some ideas of what's going on.

InnoDB does not actually lock the whole table when you perform you update query. What it does is the next: it puts a record lock which prevents any other transaction from inserting, updating, or deleting rows where the value of `coupons.user_id` is NULL.

With your query you have at the moment(which depends on user_id to be NULL), you cannot have concurrency because your transaction will run one after another, not in parallel.
Even an index on your `coupons.user_id` won't help, because when putting the lock InnoDB create a shadow index for you if you don't have one. The outcome would be the same.

So, if you want to increase your throughput, there are two options I can think of:

1. Assign a user to a coupon in async mode. Put all assignment request in a queue then process the queue in background. Might not be suitable for your business rules.
2. Decrease the number of locked records. The idea here is to lock as less records as possible while performing an update. To achieve this you can add one or more **indexed** columns to your table, then use the index in your `WHERE` clause of `Update` query.

An example of column is a product_id, or a category, maybe a user location(country, zip).
then your query will look something like this:

> UPDATE coupons SET user_id =  WHERE product_id =  user_id is NULL LIMIT 1;

And now InnoDB will lock only records with `product_id = <product_id>`. this way you you'll have concurrency.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of adding product_id. I actually am already bounding the coupons to a product_id which is indexed. Now on that same product_id, I am receiving many updates. Wanted a solution to solve for that.